# How do I fill columns first then fill rows responsively with css grids?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a dynamic list of items which I would like to display. I would like them to fill the first row of a grid adding columns as needed until the row fits the container. Next, it should fill the second row, then fill the third row, etc. I don't care about the order but it would be nice to have the items displayed from top to bottom, column by column like so:

```
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

The parent container doesn't have a fixed height. Here's what it should look like:
[image]

This works, but I have to specify the number of rows explicitly. Is there a way to do this without explicitly specifying rows / columns?

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/caffinatedmonkey/pen/vZgRvV)

Here's the order I want the grid to fill up in:

First:

```
1 2 3 4 |
```

Next (no more room on first row):

```
1 3 5 7 |
2 4 6 8 |
```

Next (no more room on second row):

```
1 4 7 10 |
2 5 8 11 |
3 6 9 12 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe your desired layout is possible with CSS Grid alone.

As I see it, you want [**`grid-auto-flow: row`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property) working until the columns fill the first row. At that point, you want to switch to `grid-auto-flow: column`.

Even if that adjustment could be scripted in, I'm not sure it would work without setting explicit heights or rows on the container.